# Where can I learn about permissions in the .NET framework?

Tags: .net, security, appdomain

I would like to see an overview of each permission that the .NET framework defines, and what possible security holes are opened by allowing an untrusted assembly access to each permission.

I would also like to know which specific permissions are allowed in a Silverlight application on the internet, which seems like a good starting point for running assemblies in a sandbox.

Also, how do I configure a new AppDomain with the permissions I want?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you have already read through the MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.aspx

Comment: yeah, which of those 50 classes do you suppose I should click on first? I have read through http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046.aspx and other articles, but so far have not found a good discussion about permissions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that (50 classes) is probably why there is no comprehensive article on the subject, especially considering that there are multiple possible enums that can be applied to the various permission attributes. Have you seen this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163701.aspx

Comment: Reading documentation is a lost art. Suggestion: click on the first, scan through to the last. It couldn't take you more than an hour or to to figure out which are the most important classes for your purpose.

Comment: @competent_tech that article looks quite useful, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the best answer, but I try. You can check [security permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ba4k1c5.aspx) as a starting point and from there [code access permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h846e9b3.aspx) might be of interest.

As with any kind of security you need to make the surface of attack as small as possible. This means you should not really bother with *all* possible permission attacks, but rather deny all permissions by default. You will only allow the minimal necessary permissions required by the application to run. Once you have a small set of permissions you can perhaps ask a more narrow question.

To configure AppDomain you can define PermissionSet and Evidence security parameters before creating a new domain. Once the domain is created it is not (theoretically) possible to escalate those privileges.

```
var setup = new AppDomainSetup
    {
        ApplicationBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(platform.Location)
    };
PermissionSet permissionSet = new PermissionSet();
permissionSet.AddPermission(
    new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read |
        FileIOPermissionAccess.PathDiscovery,
        Path.GetDirectoryName(platform.Location)));
permissionSet.AddPermission(
    new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));
var sandbox = AppDomain.CreateDomain(name, null, setup, permissionSet);
```

Code taken from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/23a9197e-3581-4a28-912d-968004488773), sample [evidence security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.evidence.aspx) and [Creating an AppDomain with limited permissions](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/10/25/247379.aspx) might also be of interest to you.